# unable to postion and fill space with jqueryui accordian and tab control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I've been struggling with positioning some jquery controls which fill the white space on screen completely.

I'm looking for a header, then under that a split screen with accrodian on the left and a tab set on the right.

I can position them, but can't get them to fill the space correctly, I've tried it with absolute positioning but it makes things look out of place further down the line when scrolling content in introduced into the tabs.

Also the content should only scroll in the tab-space, the overall screen should remain fixed and just resize its controls within the main browser.

here's my basic screen layout:`code` http://jsfiddle.net/3WhdW/1/

If you could save your solutions in fiddle that would be a great help :)

Cheers
DIG's

Comment: Which space do you want to fill? Height? Width?

Comment: both, the accordian should fill to the bottom but remain fixed width, and the tabs fill bottom and right space. basically use the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
position: absolute;
```

to create 100% width and heigth.

Please, check:
http://jsfiddle.net/3WhdW/2/
It's scroller on right. But you can avoid it using additional css styles.

Comment: That's kind of where I got too. Looks ok until you make the browser bigger. The accordion doesn't resize correctly and also a similar resize issue with the tab contents scroll area leave lots of white space below. Drag the fiddle screen out you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/3WhdW/3/ Just needed a little extra javascript to force a refresh on resize.